# What is the best way to assert the sorting logic provided by an API in Karate? Should I go with Java or Javascript

Tags: json, rest, sorting, karate

Note:- There is an API which provides a list of employee objects. I need to ensure that the empId field is sorted by ascending as well as descending order correctly.

API can accept a filter parameter like => sortBy=empId:asc or sortBy=empId:desc

[default sorting is ascending]

So the API looks like => baseUrl/employee/v1/employee?sortBy=empId:asc

So my code looks like below

```
Feature: Verify default sorting

Background:

      * def sort =
    """
       function (list)  {
            java.util.Collections.sort(list);
            return list;
        }
    """

Scenario: Verify default sorting
      Given url "api?sortBy=empId:asc"
      When method GET
      Then status 200
      * empId = $response.empList[*].empId
      * match empId == sort(empId);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

It works correctly but I am confused whether it should be written in the Java or Javascript style.

Any suggestion would be much appreciate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is fine, whatever works. In 1.X a `karate.sort()` API was introduced: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def foo = [{a: { b: 3 }}, {a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}]
* def fun = function(x){ return x.a.b }
* def bar = karate.sort(foo, fun)
* match bar == [{a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}, {a: { b: 3 }}]
```

And you can call `reverse()` on a JS array if needed as a second step.

And there is nothing wrong with using Java code, as long as it works.